Why doesn’t Rabbi Akiva use this verse instead?
In Makkot 24b, Rabbi Akiva famously comforts the sages who see foxes roaming the ruins of the Temple by saying “now that Uriah’s prophecy of the plowing of Jerusalem is fulfilled, I know Zechariah’s prophecy of the rebirth of the city will also be fulfilled.”
My question is, the rabbis were specifically crying over seeing foxes on the Temple. Rabbi Akiva should’ve quoted Eicha 5:18, which clearly states that foxes will roam the Temple, as his first pasuk of a nevuah of tragedy occurring, and then quote the Zechariah verse. Wouldn’t this pasuk from Eicha which literally mentions the foxes have been more appropriate in this context?

Was that verse a prophecy?

Eicha is from Kesuvim, only via ruach hakodesh, but Zecharia is an actual prophet.

The point was the attributing of part of Micha to Uriah, which would allow for connecting between Uriah and Zechariah, the two witnesses from Yeshayahu. Eicha, on the other hand, is attributed fully to Yirmiyahu.

@Harel13 I don’t follow. Can you clarify and also explain who these different personalities were

I recommend reading the full gemara. R"A chose a verse from Micha which he associated with a prophet named Uriah. Uriah and Zechariah were two prophets named by Yeshayahu (Isaiah) as witnesses to the promise of the redemption (https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.8.1-4?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he). Since Uriah and Zechariah are two witnesses, their respective prophecies/testamonies are dependent on one another (witnesses and testimony is the topic of Makkot).

R"A pointed out that now that Uriah's prophecy has been fulfilled, surely Zechariah's is true as well and will also come to pass. Uriah seems to have been a prophet around Yeshayahu's time, but Zechariah is the prophet who authored the eponymous book and lived in the Second Temple era.

If he had chosen a verse not related to Uriah, he would not have been able to connect it to Zechariah's more hope-filled prophecies.

@Harel13 please write this as an answer. Not comments.

@Harel13 that makes sense. But yeshayahu named Zechariah even though he would live hundreds of years later? Why would Uriah’s prophecy of the destruction of the first temple be connected to Zechariah’s prophecy of the second?

@CuriousYid I would not rush with stating a possible age problem with Zecharia son of Berekhia ben Iddo haNavi (Zecharia 1:1). Compare, Zechryahu ben YeBerekhyahu (Isaiah 8:2). Sanhedrin 104a identifies Iddo as the prophet visitting Yerovam in Kings A 13:1-34. These guys had long years of life.

@YDJ what the Gemara writes is based on Divrei Hayamim in two separate verses that mention a prophet named Ido being active around the time of Yerov'am. However, it's not evident from the Gemara or Divrei Hayamim that this is the same Ido as Zechariah's grandfather.

@CuriousYid that's a good question, but separate from why Rabbi Akiva referred to that verse, because it has to do with p'shat Tanach. I recommend asking it as a separate question.

The answer to the question, as noted in the comments, is that Megilath Eikha is written by ruach hakodesh as a book from Kethuvim and is not actual prophesy, whereas the verses quoted are from the books of neviim.
The comments raised a number of other points which seem to be addressed by the last commentary of Tosafoth on Makoth 24b
Rabbi Akiva states that the prophesy of Uriyah “Therefore, for your sake Zion shall be plowed..." are found only in the book of Micah 3:12 and we do not find them to be said by Uriyah. We can explain that the sefer Yirmiyahu 26:20 describes how Yirmiyahu prophesized about destruction of the Beith haMikdash, so that the kohanim, the false prophets, and the rest of the nation were angry with him for these prophesies. They wanted to kill Yirmiyahu. Then finally several men among the elders (ziknei ha'am) defended Yirmiyahu and said that already Micha spoke about destruction in the days of king Chizkiyahu "Zion shall be plowed" and he was not killed. The elders added that "There was also a man prophesying in the name of G-D, Uriah son of Shemaiah from Kiriath-yearim (1), who prophesied against this city and this land the same things as Jeremiah." The implication is that Uriyah said something similar to what Micha did and that is why the prophesy in the Gemara is designated in the name of Uriyah son of Shemaiah.
There is a difficulty with understanding why Rabbi Akiva is bringing the prophesy of Zekhariya 8:4 "There shall yet be elderly men and elderly women sitting in the streets of Jerusalem!” It was made during the Second Beith haMikdash (BhM"K), and by the time of Rabbi Akiva the Temple was destroyed. Thus, the prophesy was not fulfilled (Beeroth haMaim). Are the words of Zekhariah about the World to Come or about this world prior to Geula/Redemption, and how would Rabbi Akiva be comforted with verses of redemption that will be fulfilled? The answer can be found from masekheth Pesachim, second part of which is called Pesach Sheini. On daf 68a gemara explains gzerah shaveh regarding this verse by using the connection מִשְׁעַנְתּוֹ and מִשְׁעַנְתִּי:
"This idea is derived from a different source as well. Rabbi Shmuel bar Naḥmani said that Rabbi Yonatan said: In the future the righteous will resurrect the dead, as it is stated: “Old men and old women shall yet again dwell in the streets of Jerusalem, and every man with his staff in his hand for very age” (Zechariah 8:4). And the staff will then be used as it was used by Gehazi when Elisha sent him to bring the son of the Shunamite woman back to life, as it is written: “And you shall lay my staff on the face of the child” (II Kings 4:29)."
I.e. just like Elisha brought life to the dead child, so the verse is speaking about the time of Revival of the Dead, which is for sure after BhM"K 1 and BhM"K 2. MaHaRSh"A adds here that rabbi Akiva also saw that G-d made sure that nobody could have nachath ruach in the land until the time of redemption, even the foxes.
In other words, it looks good to refer to the verse in Yeshayahu 8:1-4 who mentions two witnesses of redemption kohein Uriyah and Zekhariahu. However, Tosafos does not go this way, even though the fathers of the witness Zekhariyahu and the prophet Zekhariah seem to have the same name. That's a pretty but an unfortunate trap.

(1) According to Seder haDoros, Year 3298, Uriah ben Shemaya was a kohein from a low status family. Furthemore, the story in Yirmiyahu 26 tells that that king Yehoiakim wanted to kill Uriah. Uriyah ran to Egypt. Agents of Yehoiakim found him there and brought him back. King Yohoiakim killed Uriah by the sword. I.e. the gemara brings the memory of Uriah's sacrifice by mentioning his name, rather than Micha.
