How did Zechariah the son of Berechiah die?
Inspired by this question on Biblical Hermeneutics
The Christian New Testament in Matthew 23:35 says:

And that upon you may come all the righteous blood shed upon the earth, from the blood of righteous Abel unto the blood of Zechariah, son of Barachias, whom ye slew between the temple and the altar.

There's a debate in Christianity as to whether this refers to the same Zechariah who wrote the prophetic book of Zechariah. The Bible records a different Zechariah (the son of Jehoiada) being killed in the temple, but nothing about the death of Zechariah the son of Berechiah. My question is, according to Jewish tradition, how did Zechariah the son of Berechiah, the author of the book, die? Is this New Testament text referencing a known contemporary tradition?

Welcome to Mi Yodeya.
I actually wrote an essay for a course at uni on this topic about a year ago.
The NT is referencing a Jewish tradition that appears in several other sources in variant forms. The oldest inherently Jewish version was preserved in Vitae Prophetarum, a Greek apocryphal work describing the lives of various Tanachic prophets (including extra-biblical tidbits) that many scholars believe was translated from a now-lost Hebrew vorlage authored by Jews, perhaps circa the 1st century CE. David Satran, Biblical Prophets in Byzantine Palestine: Reassessing the Lives of the Prophets, Leiden 1995, is of the opinion that the work is of Christian Byzantine origins, but concedes that the stories of Zechariah b. Jehoiada and Isaiah are likely much older Jewish traditions.
In the chapter on the life of Zechariah b. Jehoiada it says (C. C. Torrey, The Lives of the Prophets: Greek Text and Translation, Philadelphia, PA 1946, p. 47):

"He was of Jerusalem, the son of Jehoiada the priest, the prophet whom Joash king of Judah slew beside the alter, whose blood the house of David shed within the sanctuary, in the court. The priests buried him beside his father.
From that time on there were portentous appearances in the temple, and the priests could see no vision of angels of God, nor give forth oracles from the inner sanctuary; nor were they able to inquire with the ephod, nor to give answer to the people by Urim and Thummim, as in former time."

As you can see, the story is about Zechariah b. Jehoiada, not Zechariah b. Berechiah. From your OP, I gather that you're probably aware of various explanations for why the NT references Ben Berechiah, so I won't get into that. Suffice it to say that the Jewish versions have always, to my knowledge, recounted this theme of the blood of the prophet Zechariah as referring to Ben Jehoiada.
Several more traditional Jewish sources include a variant of this tradition in the form of an aggada describing what happened when the Babylonian general Nebuzaradan came to Jerusalem. The chronologically oldest source that contains this version is the Jerusalem Talmud, tractate Ta'anit 4:6 (often 4:5 in printed editions) (my translation from MS Leiden):

"Rabbi Yohanan said: "80000 priestly youths were killed over the blood of Zechariah."
Rabbi Yudan asked Rabbi Aha: "Where did they kill Zechariah? In the Women's Court or in the Court of Israel? He replied: "Not in the Court of Israel nor in  the Women's Court but in the Priestly Court, and they did not take care of his blood as one would with the blood of a ram or a stag. There it says "that person shall pour out its blood and cover it with earth." However, here the case was that "I set her blood on the bare rock". And why? "so that it may stir [My] fury and to take vengeance, that is why I set her blood on the bare rock without cover."
Seven transgressions were committed by Israel that day. They killed a priest, and a prophet, and a judge, and spilled clean blood. And defiled the Court. And it was a Sabbath and Yom Kippur.
And when Nebuzardan came here he saw the blood bubbling. He said to them: "What is the nature of this?" They replied: "It is the blood of oxen and sheep and rams that we had sacrificed on the altar." They brought oxen and rams and sheep and he slaughtered them upon it and still the blood bubbled. And since they did not admit [the truth] to him, he hung them on the gallows. They said: "This is because the Holy One, Blessed is He demands his blood from us." They said to him: "That is the blood of a priest and prophet and judge who prophesied against us all that you are doing to us and we rose upon him and killed him." And so he brought 80000 priestly youths and slaughtered them, and still the blood bubbled. In that hour, he [Nebuzardan] scolded it and said to it: "What do you wish, to fell your entire nation over you?" With this, the Holy One, Blessed is He was filled with mercy and said: "What with that he is flesh and blood and cruel but has mercy for My children. I, upon whom it is said "for your God is a compassionate God, who will not fail you nor let you perish and will not forget the covenant of your forefathers" must be all the more so." He motioned to [the blood] and it was swallowed in its place."

There are several chronologically later versions of this aggadic tradition in other sources: Peskita de'Rav Kahana 15:7 (Mandelbaum edition, pp. 257-259), Eicha Rabbah 4:13 (4:16 in some versions; and several shorter references in other places in Eicha Rabbah), Kohelet Rabbah 10:4, and more. Each version subtly edited the tradition, altering sometimes extensively the moral of the story. In the Jerusalem Talmud, the story is presented as part of a compilation of stories and traditions related to the destruction of the two Temples and the tragic end of the Bar Kokhba Revolt. The gist of the story here is that the Jews sinned and brought the punishment upon themselves, but in the end God will have mercy. In several later versions, the blame gradually shifts from the Jews to Zechariah himself (Kohelet Rabbah states explicitly that Zechariah brought his death upon himself and is also to blame for the deaths of the people killed by Nebuzardan!).
In my essay, I argued that the NT also subtly altered the tradition, and this is most evident in the Matthian version. This version, as opposed to the Lukian version, uses the Greek phrase αἷμα δίκαιον, which means "righteous blood". Some English translators translate it to mean "innocent blood", but the Greek phrase is nearly consistently used in the LXX as a translation of the Hebrew "דַּם צַדִּיקִים" (blood of the righteous).1 I believe that it was the author's intent to reference the verse in Lamentations 4:13 "It was for the sins of her prophets, the iniquities of her priests, who had shed in her midst the blood of the righteous", whose LXX translation likewise uses the phrase αἷμα δίκαιον for "blood of the righteous". The idea presented in the verse in Lamentations is that the Judahites are to be blamed for all of the bad things that befell them, because they had killed their prophets and priests. The NT draws a connection between the sins described in Lamentations and the sins of its story's present (the death of Jesus, supposedly the fault of the Jews) and uses the tradition of the blood of Zechariah as proof that the Jews (equated with the Judahites) are prophet-killers and deserve to be punished. In this, the NT identified the "blood of the righteous" of Lamentations with the blood of the prophets and priests killed by the Jews.
In my opinion, the subtle editing of the Jewish version in later midrashic compilations was a reaction - at least in part - to this Christian polemic. Jewish exegetes used their versions to argue against the Christian version: In the Eicha Rabbah version, the phrase "blood of the righteous" clearly refers to the masses slaughtered by Nebuzardan to appease Zechariah's bubbling blood. And the aggadic unit ends with the phrase "and upon that time it is said: "It was for the sins of her prophets, the iniquities of her priests, who had shed in her midst the blood of the righteous" (Lam 4:13) - upon the death of the Judahites at the hand of Nebuzardan, not upon the deaths of the priests and prophets killed earlier by the Judahites. And, of course, all versions end with God's mercy towards the Judahites, as opposed to the NT's view, which is that Jews are undeserving of mercy.
Point is, yes, the NT is referencing a contemporary, and perhaps even older Jewish tradition, but it altered it in a way that suited its own exegetical needs. I would say that the "purest" (i.e., least polemically altered) versions are those presented in the Vitae Prophetarum and the Jerusalem Talmud.2
As for the death of Zechariah b. Berechiah in Jewish sources, to my knowledge the only mention of his death is in relation to the end of the prophetic period when Alexander conquered the Land of Israel. He seems to have died more or less at the same time as the prophets Haggai and Malachi, and likely in a natural way. For example (Seder Olam Zuta):

"And in [the days of Meshulam, son of Zerubbabel] the Greek Empire rose up and ruled, during the 52nd year of the Persian and Median Empire. And Haggai, Zechariah and Malachi died. And prophecy left Israel."


1 Such is the case in the LXX's translation of Deut 19:10, 21:8, 27:25; Kgs II 21:16, 24:4; Jer 26:15; Ps 106:38. The one exception which translates the phrase "דם נקי" (clean blood) as αἷμα δίκαιον is Prov 6:17, however it is generally agreed that the LXX of Proverbs as we have it today is vastly different from the septuagints of the other books of the Bible. Moreover, as T. A. W. Van der Louw, Transformations in the Septuagint: Towards an Interaction of Septuagint Studies and Translation Studies, Leuven, Paris and Dudley, MA 2007, pp. 308-309 pointed out, it's quite possible that αἷμα δίκαιον was used in this verse to contrast the "לשון שקר" (lying tongue) in the same verse, which is translated by the phonetically similar γλῶσσα ἄδικος.
2 There is, however, a slight possibility that the version of the midrash preserved in Pesikta de'Rav Kahana 15:7 echoes a tradition similar to the one brought in the NT, through which the story of the blood of the prophet Zechariah could be related to Zechariah b. Berechiah/b. Jeberechiah. In this version of the story, the midrash is presented as an exposition on the words "[Jerusalem] was filled with righteousness, but now murderers" (Isaiah 1:21). After a note by Rabbi Yudah b. Rabbi Simon on the immoral downfall of Jerusalem, it says:

"But now murderers [fill Jerusalem]" - they commit murders. There they killed Zechariah and Uriah."

And from there the midrash continues along more or less the same lines as the version in the Jerusalem Talmud. However, the mention of Uriah is significant. The prophet Uriah who was killed by the Judahites was Uriah b. Shemaiah from Kiryath-jearim (Jeremiah 26:20-23). But mentioning Zechariah with Uriah seems to have been intended to evoke memories of Zechariah b. Jeberechiah and Uriah the Priest, Isaiah's two witnesses who testify to the downfall of Judah's enemies (Isaiah 8:1-4), and in the aggadah, the coming redemption (see e.g. Makkot 24b linked below). This version of the midrash appears to implicitly state that the Jews were so far gone in evilness, that they even murdered the two individuals who were supposed to herald the coming of the days of peace! In traditional Jewish sources, Zechariah b. Jeberechiah is identified with Zechariah b. Berechiah (see for example: Babylonian Talmud, Tractate Makkot 24b). As for Uriah the Priest, there are various suggestions, but the Pesikta's own suggestion is that he is indeed to be identified with Uriah b. Shemaiah (13:12).
Of course, there is no evidence that this is anything other than the editor of the Pesikta's own development of a popular aggadic unit, but it is possible that he based it on some now-lost oral or written tradition that was similar to the one that found its way to the NT.

Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of the possibility that the NT is referring to the son of Jehoiada. I do appreciate the additional context regarding him. I was curious if there is any tradition regarding the other Zechariah, i.e. is it at all plausible that he also was killed in the temple? If tradition is limited to "he died", well, I guess I have to accept that :-) This seems like a case where the argument from silence is very strong though.

@user111403 hey, see the second note I added which I hope addresses your question.

Much appreciated, have a checkmark :-)

I've been interested in this for years. Thank you!

By the way, we discussed the difference between Zecharia the prophet of the 2nd Temple and the Zecharia of the 1st Temple here (fathers having the same name). https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/144235/why-doesn-t-rabbi-akiva-use-this-verse-instead/144291#144291. Both Zecharias were kohanim and so was Uriah.
